# Add webmasters to migration list

Tags: feature-request, migration-path-request

I stick primarily to the PHP tag, and I notice that there are quite a few topics being closed that could probably be moved to webmasters.stackexchange.com instead, but it's not on the list.

I'd imagine that there are a number of related tags that could also benefit from this, ie. JavaScript, CSS, HTML, etc.

Answer (score 2):

We can't have a target for every site. There are only 5 migration targets (MSO+4), and webmasters doesn't make the cut (8th most frequently migrated to).

Comment: That's lame. :I